# How can I move the legend from the plot to the appropriate place?

Tags: python, plot, fuzzy

[membership function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3MhA.png)
membership function in fuzzy algorithm and the place of the legend is wrong how I can change it's place

Comment: Please share a piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your image if you use matplotlib, using loc='upper center' or loc='best'

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
plt.plot(x, y1, label ='1')
plt.plot(x, y2, label ='2')
  
# Function add a legend  
plt.legend(loc='upper center')
  
# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

But if you want to put it in a specific x,y coordinate

```
plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(x, y))
```